# Testing an http request where in success call another function with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, http, jasmine

I have a controller with an http request. On success it calls another function and I do not know how to test it. I am new to angular.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['']);
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) { 
$scope.source = '';
$scope.destination = '';
var selectedFiles = [];

$scope.deleteFiles = function(source) {
    if (source == $scope.source) {
        selectedFiles = selectedFilesSource;
    } else if (source == $scope.destination) {
        selectedFiles = selectedFilesDestination;
    }

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'deleteFiles.php',
        data:
        {
            "sourcePath": source,
            "selectedFiles": selectedFiles
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        if (source == $scope.source) {
            $scope.showFiles(source, 'source');
        } else if (source == $scope.destination) {
            $scope.showFiles(source, 'destination');
        }
    });
};
```

My testing file is like that:

```
describe("Testing to MainController", function(){

beforeEach(module('myApp'));

var mainController, scope, httpBackend, http;

beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend, $http) {
    scope = $rootScope;
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    http = $http;

    httpBackend.when('POST', 'deleteFiles.php', function(data){return{"sourcePath": "source", "selectedFiles": ''}})
       .respond(?????);
    mainController = $controller('MainController', {
        $scope: scope,
        $http: http
    });
}));



    it('should call showFiles if sourcepath is source', function() {
  scope.source = 'files/set1';
  scope.deleteFiles('files/set1');
  httpBackend.expectPOST('deleteFiles.php');
  httpBackend.flush();
  expect(scope.showFiles).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

});

Error message: Expected a spy, but got Function.
I do not how to use spy in here and I do not understand what should I have in httpBackend .respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you promise is resolved successfully then `$scope.showFiles(source, 'source');` function is called. So create a spy on showFiles.

```
it('should call showFiles if sourcepath is source', function() {
  spyOn(scope, 'showFiles'); 
  scope.source = 'files/set1';
  scope.deleteFiles('files/set1');
  httpBackend.expectPOST('deleteFiles.php');
  httpBackend.flush();
  expect(scope.showFiles).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: and what should I have in respond of httpBackend?

Comment: There should be mock response with the same data structure which you have in actual response

Answer (score 0):

```
it('', function() {
  spyOn(scope, 'showFiles');
  scope.source = 'files/set1';
  scope.deleteImages('images/set1');
  // rest of your test ...
});
```